# Some webpages don't load properly in any Linux distro on Thinkpad T420

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, google-chrome

Recently I can't use Facebook, Youtube and some other webpages in any Linux distro that I install on my Thinkpad T420.

I've been using Xubuntu for about one year and it happened about three weeks ago. Back then, I was able to use Google Chrome to replace Firefox but now not even Opera can load, e.g, www.facebook.com or www.youtube.com.

I am typing from a fresh install of Xubuntu.

[image: What happens when I try to load YouTube]

Comment: Is this happening only in Linux? Have you tried it in a Windows install on the same machine or you don't have one? The problem might be from a proxy or VPN you're using or your router, so you should make a few more tests in order to rule out some of the possible reasons. For example try connecting to the internet from another ISP and see what happens.

Comment: Connecting to another ISP worked! So how can I fix it on my router?

Comment: Now there are two possible reasons I can think of - your router or your ISP. Unfortunately I have no idea how to help you about both of them. You can check whether there is a proxy or a VPN configured for your router but beyond that I have no idea what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues recently using "ad" heavy sites like facebook, etc..   not sure if the problem is the same but these site would lock up the browser and ultimately the computer - What I found was that (after benchmarking the machine) Any web page that had lots of "ad" implementations like facebook or youtube or like buzzfeed (smh) the one page would be using more than 50% of the ram i had installed - What I did to resolve it was increase my ram to 2 gigs and using 32 bit system rather than a 64 bit - (im running intel core duo with 2 gigs of ram) - no more issues now bud - hopefully this helps in your troubleshooting